# why items child of nav does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

To be brief, i have a navbar, when i click on the button in the `<li>`, the child div with the class `.nav-collapse` or `.item-list` should appears. One `<li>` works and the other does not.

```js
var menuItems = $('.menu li.item-child');
menuItems.each(function(el) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var activatingA = $this.find('>a');
  var btn = '<button><span><span class="visuallyhidden">show submenu for “' +
    activatingA.text() + '”</span></span></button>';
  activatingA.append(btn);

  $this.find("button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("el", $(this).parents('li.item-child'));
    $(this).parents('li.item-child').toggleClass("open");
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', function(index, attr) {
      return attr == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.header-synopric21 {
     background: none;
}
 .header-main {
     background-color: gray;
}
 .header-main .header-wrapper {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: baseline;
     padding: 3rem 0;
     width: 118rem;
     max-width: 118rem;
     margin: auto;
}
 .header-main .profil {
     color: #fafbfc;
     display: flex;
}
 .header-main .profil a {
     width: 4.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin-right: 0.2rem;
}
 .header-main .profil a:hover {
     background-color: gray;
}
 .header-main .profil p {
     line-height: 3rem;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
 .header-main .profil img {
     width: 1.4rem;
     height: 2rem;
}
 .menu-syno {
     background-color: gray;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav {
     margin: auto;
     min-width: 50rem;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: row;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
     margin-right: 1rem;
     flex-basis: 14.5rem;
     width: 14.5rem;
     min-width: 14.5rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li:hover {
     background-color: blue;
     color: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.is-active {
     background-color: blue;
     color: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li li {
     margin-right: 0;
     padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li > .nav-link {
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     outline: transparent;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child {
     display: flex;
     position: relative;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     width: 91rem;
     min-width: 91rem;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     top: 6rem;
     padding: 0;
     margin-top: -0.6rem;
     border-radius: 0;
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
     z-index: 9;
     grid-template-areas: 'top top top top top top top' 'left left center center center right right';
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-list {
     grid-area: top;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track {
     background-color: blue;
    /*******/
    /*******/
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide {
    /*******/
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 1px;
    /*******/
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div {
     padding: 2rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div:hover {
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div:hover a {
     color: blue;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div h2 {
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div h2 a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: "arial";
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-track div.slick-slide > div h2 button {
     display: none;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-direction: row;
     width: 100%;
     flex-basis: 100%;
     background-color: blue;
     border-top: 1px solid blue;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     height: 5rem;
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     grid-area: center;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li {
     padding: 0;
     display: flex !important;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li.slick-active {
     font-weight: bold;
     background: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li.slick-active a {
     color: #1660bc;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li:hover {
     background-color: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li:hover a {
     color: blue;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list ul.slick-dots li a {
     color: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-arrow {
     background-color: blue;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 9;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-arrow.slick-prev {
     left: unset;
     right: 0;
     text-align: right;
     grid-area: left;
     border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-arrow.slick-prev:before {
     content: "";
     background-image: url("../img/arrow-prev.svg");
     display: block;
     width: 1rem;
     height: 1rem;
     background-size: cover;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     right: 1rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-arrow.slick-next {
     right: unset;
     left: 0;
     grid-area: right;
     border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .item-list .slick-arrow.slick-next:before {
     content: "";
     background-image: url("../img/arrow-prev.svg");
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     display: block;
     width: 1rem;
     height: 1rem;
     background-size: cover;
     margin-left: 1rem;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child ul.nav-submenu li {
     background-color: blue;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #6496d1;
     text-align: left;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child ul.nav-submenu li a {
     color: white;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child ul.nav-submenu li:hover {
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child ul.nav-submenu li:hover a {
     color: blue;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .nav-collapse {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 6rem;
     padding: 0;
     width: max-content;
     margin-top: -0.6rem;
     border-radius: 0;
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
     left: 0;
     transform: none;
     z-index: 9;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child.open .nav-collapse, .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child.open .item-list {
     display: grid;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child.open > button {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child .visuallyhidden {
     border: 0;
     clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
     height: 1px;
     margin: -1px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 1px;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child > button {
     background-color: transparent;
     border: none;
     margin-left: 0.33rem;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 .menu-syno .navbar-nav > li.item-child button > span {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 1rem;
     height: 1rem;
     background: url("../img/arrow-white.svg") center no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}
 .navbar-light {
     padding: 0;
     background-color: gray;
}
 .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
     color: blue;
     border-color: blue;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     border-radius: 0;
     margin-left: 1rem;
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
     padding: 8px;
}
 .navbar-light .navbar-toggler:hover {
     background-color: blue;
}
 .navbar-light .navbar-toggler:hover .navbar-toggler-icon {
     background-image: url('../img/menu-hover.svg');
}
 .navbar-light .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
     background-image: url('../img/menu.svg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
 
    <div class="menu-syno navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu-syno">
        <ul role="list" data-region="header" class="menu navbar-nav">


            <li role="listitem" class="item-child -aaaa">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">A PROPOS 1</a>


                <ul role="list" class="nav-collapse" id="nav-menu-item-464052098">
                    <div class="nav-collapse-inner">
                        <ul role="list" class="nav-submenu">
                            <li role="listitem">
                                <a href="/" target="_self" class="nav-link" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Nos expertises</a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="listitem">
                                <a href="/charte-de-bonne-conduite" class="nav-link" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/2466">Charte de bonne conduite</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>


            </li>


            <li role="listitem">
                <a href="/recherche" class="nav-link" data-drupal-link-system-path="recherche">Recherche</a>
            </li>
      
        <li role="listitem" class="item-child -bbbb">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">A PROPOS 2</a>


                <ul role="list" class="nav-collapse" id="nav-menu-item-464052098-1">
                    <div class="nav-collapse-inner">
                        <ul role="list" class="nav-submenu">
                            <li role="listitem">
                                <a href="/" target="_self" class="nav-link" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Nos expertises</a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="listitem">
                                <a href="/charte-de-bonne-conduite" class="nav-link" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/2466">Charte de bonne conduite</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>


            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hey, it's done, sorry for the delay, i was cleaning the code

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.

Comment: @Paulie_D please take a look, i cleaned the code

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a solution. actually i had to do this :

```
$this.find("button").click(function(event) {
```

insted of :

```
menuItems.find("button").click(function(event) {
```